# Is there any way to retrieve a object in a test from a Provide in Guice?

Tags: java, junit, inversion-of-control, guice

I'm trying to get a Object in a JUnit test from a @Provides in a module which isn't @Inject**ed** therefore I cannot get it by the injector.

Is there any way that I can call the method without injecting the class?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question lacks an example test case, it's a bit difficult to give you an exact answer, however, you can do arbitrary with this junit5 extension: https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

per the example:

```
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class, InjectExtension.class })
class MyControllerTest {
 @InjectMocks
 private MyController myController;
 @InjectionSource
 private SecurityService securityService;
```

will put securityService into myController if the field matches type and name exactly. From there you could either mock that field or provide your own implementation